# how to delete n number of files in directory using python

Tags: python

I have a cat and dog image dataset. I converted into two folders (cat and dog) each folder contains roughly 10000 images. So Far I don't want 10000 images, I need only 2000 images in each folder. How to automate this in python.

I know to delete a file X, I could use `os.remove(X)`
similarly to delete a folder `os.rmdir(dir_)`

But I'm wondering **how could i delete randomly n files in each folder effectively**

So Far I tried,

```
dogs_dir=os.listdir('dogs')
cats_dir=os.listdir('cats')

selected_dogs = np.random.choice(dogs_dir,8000)
selected_cats = np.random.choice(cats_dir,8000)

for file_ in selected_dogs:
    os.remove('dogs/'+file_)

for file_ in selected_cats:
    os.remove('cats/'+file_)
```

The above code does the job for me, but I'm wondering is their effective way so that i could remove complexity in my code.

Any help would be appreciable.

I'm using ubuntu 17.10, For Now linux based solution is sufficient, but If it compatible with windows also then it's more appreciable.

Comment: Please clarify: a) OS: Linux, Windows, you need universal solution, b) are you aware of [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/shutil.html) ?

Comment: Your code seems reasonable. The only things I'd say are: 1) [`np.random.choice`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) samples with replacement by default, pass `replace=False` to avoid picking the same file twice 2) If you want, you can avoid using NumPy for this task by just using [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.sample).

Comment: @AlexYu - updated to the question

Comment: You can also consider moving 8000 files to another directory and then deleting that entire directory

Comment: @jdehesa - I'll take this in mind, thanks for the advice.

Comment: @ycx - yeah I thought this also, but for moving an entire directory won't require me a loop, but moving a selected 8k files requires me a loop. this is what I want to skip.

Comment: I was going to suggest a similar approach.. however, instead of copying 8000 files, just copy random 2000 files to another folder and delete the existing folder with rest of the 8000+ files. That should save some processing time as well.

Comment: Kind of a duplicate of [Delete all but 1000 random files in a directory](https://superuser.com/questions/1186350/delete-all-but-1000-random-files-in-a-directory)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems okay to me.

A few adjustments I would make:

1. It's better to use the `os` library so it should be cross-platform. This is because, when you write `os.remove('dogs/'+file_)`, the `/` is not cross platform. Would be better to use `os.remove(os.path.join('dogs', file_))`.
2. You're wasting a lot of space holding the list of filenames to delete (Two lists of 10000 strings). If it doesn't matter to you which images to keep you could save a little bit of space (20%) by slicing:

   ```py
   dogs_delete=os.listdir('dogs')[2000:]  # Take the last 8000 images
   for file_ in dogs_delete:
       os.remove(os.path.join('dogs', file_))
   ```

   If it does matter which images to keep, better to generate indices (less space):

   ```py
   dogs_dir=os.listdir('dogs')
   for num in random.sample(len(dogs_dir), 8000):
       os.remove(os.path.join('dogs', dogs_dir[num]))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) and the [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html) module:

```
from pathlib import Path
import random

def delete_images(directory, number_of_images, extension='jpg'):
    images = Path(directory).glob(f'*.{extension}')
    for image in random.sample(images, number_of_images):
        image.unlink()

delete_images('dogs', 8000)
delete_images('cats', 8000)
```

[`Path('cats/').glob('*.jpg')`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob) returns a list of `Path` objects that represent files in the `cats` directory whose filenames end with `.jpg`.

[`random.sample(<something>, 8000)`](https://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.sample) takes a random sample of 8000 items from a list.

[`Path().unlink()`](https://docs.python.org/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.unlink) deletes a file.

Comment: @MohamedThasinah `pathlib` was added in Python 3.4 which was 5 years ago. I think it's not used much because it's not available on Python 2.